# On Windows, how to pdflatex compile while pdf is open with Acrobat?

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I use `pdflatex` on Windows to compile my `.tex` code and I can't compile until I close my `.pdf` file. This is what he tells me:

```
 latexmk -e '$pdflatex=q/pdflatex %O -shell-escape %S/' -pdf -g .\title-page.tex

! I can't write on file `title-page.pdf'.
Please type another file name for output:
```

I wouldn't want to use another filename each time I compile.

Comment: You can't. If you want to use adobe reader you need an editor that closes the file before the compilation.

Comment: use SumatraPDF instead.